# How to randomly change inline images on page load and each refresh, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

What is the best lightweight way to randomly show inline images <strike>from a folder</strike> on each refresh  or on load a page ? using jQuery.

like jQuery version of this http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/random-image.html

**Update: 24 April**

**This is exactly what i want i just need unobtrusive jQuery version of this**

```
<div class=”me-box”>

<script language=”JavaScript”>
function banner() { } ; b = new banner() ; n = 0
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me.jpg’ >”
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me2.jpg’ >”
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me4.jpg’ >”
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me5.jpg’ >”
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me6.jpg’ >”
b[n++]= “<img name=randimg src=’images/me3.jpg’ >”
i=Math.floor(Math.random() * n) ;
document.write( b[i] )
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found solution here

http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/

Comment: author of that page posted saying he fixed an IE bug in july, if you hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery by itself can not read a folder's contents. Unless you do some magic like name the files for example 1.jpg, 2.jpg and include an upperbound in the script.

You should probably use a server side language to read the folder and pass some JSON to your JavaScript. Then just loop the JSON and display.

```
$.getJSON('get/files', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(image) {
        $('#my-div ul').append('<li><img src="' + image + '" alt="" />');
    });

});
```

Comment: @metal-gear-solid Are you talking about paths for every image in your random selection?

Comment: I'm making a site and site's home page has banner image , I want to show 3-4 images on randomly basis. whenever user will go to site he will see images has changed.

Comment: I need unobtrusive jquery version of this http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/random-image.html

Comment: And I want to make this thing easy for client. client can't add source but he can add. images in specific folder with any specific name order. like i can instruct him to add images like this banner-1.jpg, banner2.jpg .....

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on how many pics you are talking about and if they will change frequently. Let's say there aren't many and the list will stay pretty much the same. You could through their file names into an array and then randomly generate a number based on the length of the array's index.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rndNumber;
    var displayPictures = new Array();
    displayPictures[0...n] = 'filename.jpg';

    rndNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*displayPictures.length));

    $('#picture_tag_id_name').attr('src', 'images/'+displayPictures[rndNumber]);

});
```

When I tried this on a site, I used inline PHP to loop through the contents of the image folder and 'echo' out the lines that populate the array with the strings of all the image paths.

May not be the best way but it is a way.

Comment: @PortableWorld - see my comments under @alex's answer.