# why this jquery code doesn't work if i add class to <P>

Tags: jquery, xhtml

It works

```
var tip = "<p>Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
tip +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";


if($("div#maincontent a[href*='.pdf']").length>0){
    $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
```

but it not

```
var tip = "<p class="adobe-reader-download">Most computers will open PDF documents automatically, but you may need to download <a title='Link to Adobe website-opens in a new window'";
tip +=" href='http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html' target='_blank'>Adobe Reader</a>.</p>";


if($("div#maincontent a[href*='.pdf']").length>0){
    $("div#maincontent").children(":last-child").after(tip);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using double quotes here at where it says `adobe-reader-download`

```
var tip = "<p class="adobe-reader-download">
```

Try this:

```
var tip = "<p class=\"adobe-reader-download\">
```

**Note:** If you use single quotes for your entire string, you won't need to escape double quotes.

Comment: thanks working now. pls answer my this question also if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696321/how-to-randomly-change-inline-images-on-page-load-and-each-refresh-using-jquery